# How to get a value from color picker in Javascript and use the color value later

Tags: javascript

When the user chose a colour in the colour picker.
How can I get the colour value and use the colour value later in the code?

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<label for="color">Please chose a color </label>
<input type="color" id="color" name="color2">
  
 <script>
        let userColor= document.querySelector("#color").value
        console.log(userColor)
 </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Get the value with `onchange` event:

```js
document.querySelector("#color").onchange = e => {
   console.log(e.target.value)
}
```

```html
<label for="color">Please chose a color </label>
<input type="color" id="color" name="color2">
```

Answer (score 0):

You Should add a change event listener to color input like this

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<label for="color">Please chose a color </label>
<input type="color" id="color" name="color2">

 <script>
        let userColor= document.querySelector("#color");
   
   userColor.addEventListener("change",(e) => {
          console.log(e.target.value)
   })
        
 </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `addEventListener`, so then you can call to one function every time this cganges:

```
<body>
<label for="color">Please chose a color </label>
<input type="color" id="color" name="color2">
<button onclick="whatColor()">ASDASD</button>

<script>
    let color = "";
    let userColor = document.querySelector("#color");
    userColor.addEventListener("change", myFunction);
    function myFunction() {
        console.log(userColor.value);
        color = userColor.value;
    }
    function whatColor() {
        console.log(color);
    }
</script>
</body>
```

This will call `myFunction` every time your input value changes. For making this write something, you will need to change the color, for make sure you change color, you should click outside the input when you choose your color.

You can also use `userColor.addEventListener("input", myFunction);` who will print every time you click on input

Comment: Thanks. After I got the value of the colour how to use it later on?

Comment: You can use it like if you write text by your own. You can use it where you need to. I.E.: **document.body.style.backgroundColor = userColor.value;** If you use this in your function, it will change body's backgroundColor everytime you chose a color.

Comment: I want to assign the user-selected colour value to a variable and use it later. How can i achieve it?

Comment: You can just save the value in variable and call it when you need it. Add *let color = ' ' ;* before *let userColor = document.querySelector("#color");* and set color value to your color picker value. Use: **color = userColor.value;** in your function

Comment: let color =""
    let userColor = document.querySelector("#color");
    userColor.addEventListener("change", myFunction);
    function myFunction() {
       color= userColor.value
    }
    console.log(color)           I tried this but didn't work

Comment: I will edit this awnser with the full code, it should work for you.